# Missing cmssbx28 font (and other sizes)

Tags: fonts, texlive

This is trying to build ods (https://github.com/patmorin/ods.git) (the "Open Data Structures in *" by Pat Morin set of books), and it complains it can't build cmssbx28. Running `mktexmf cmssbx28` (and the other missing sizes) gives "!I can't find file 'cmssbx28'."

This is texlive 2019 on Fedora 31. Am I missing some package? I can't find anything relevant with my limited font-fu.

Comment: There isn't any 28-point `cmssbx` font (or any other computer modern font).  However using a type-1 font, a plain TeX call for such a font would be `cmssbx10 at 28pt`.  I haven't looked at the referenced files, so don't know whether this is plain TeX, LaTeX, or some other flavor.  However, any scalable font can be set in sizes other than the base design size using an appropriate calling syntax.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, it is LaTeX.

Comment: For LaTeX, something like `\fontfamily{cmss}\fontseries{bx}\fontsize{28}(32}\selectfont` should work.  Not tested; someone with more current experience in resetting fonts in LaTeX I'm sure can verify or correct this.